# Why i am getting mail delayed in Phpmailer?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer for sending mail, But email is sending so late to the customer, sometimes it didn't send. Can anyone tell me what is the reason?

My PHPmailer setting:-

```
public function sendemail($to,$msg,$subject)
{
    require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();                     
        $mail->Host = 'maddbas.nexcess.net';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Username = 'myusername'; 
        $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
        $mail->Port       = 587;    
        $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'test');
        $mail->addReplyTo('test@gmail.com', 'test');
        $mail->addAddress($to);

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $msg;
        $mail->send();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `ssl://maddbas.nexcess.net`? Also, comment `$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";`

Comment: Don't suggest random things without a reason; if those things were wrong, it would not send at all.

Comment: I can see you're using an old version of PHPMailer - upgrade now. Base your code on the examples provided (i.e. with error checking), and set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3` so you can see what is taking the time; post your results in your question.

Comment: How you thought it is a random thing. I've used it before in projects. But generally, I use CodeIgniter built-in email library.

Comment: Sometimes the server configurations will affect.

Comment: @abhishek kumar, did you try CodeIgniter's built-in email library. You can debug the email sent by adding `$this->email->print_debugger();`. Please refer https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: I removed the phpmyadmin tag because this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, This isn't PHPMailer issue.
This is happening because of your hosting provider!

Some hosting provider doesn't allow you to set from recipient except your own domain name or it may delay mail.

If you have cpanel access, You can **track delivery** report in email tab.

I would you like to suggest you to use strong email providers!

Like: 
**Elasticemail**
**Sendgrid**
**Mailgun**
And so on....